# Experiencing latency with haproxy load balancer

Tags: performance, load-balancing, haproxy, latency, round-robin

I'm experiencing high latency with haproxy load balancer when backend configuration uses private network IP addresses.

But when I replace backend server addresses with public IP address or Reverse DNS name I experience no latency.

- What is causing the latency?
- If one uses public IP or fqdn or
  Reverse DNS name, does network traffic bypasses haproxy?
- Is it
  allowed to use public IP or fqdn or Reverse DNS name for backend
  servers in haproxy conf?

**Configuration With Private Network IP Addresses**

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 18000

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option  httplog

    timeout client 30s
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout server 30s

frontend www
    bind *:80
    default_backend webservers

backend webservers
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 10.0.0.20:80
    server server2 10.0.0.30:80
```

**Configuration With Reverse DNS or Public IP Addresses**

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 18000

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option  httplog

    timeout client 30s
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout server 30s

frontend www
    bind *:80
    default_backend webservers

backend webservers
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 90-80-70-40.aws.com:80
    server server2 90-80-70-50.aws.com:80
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a DNS issue on the host Windows machines. Added entries to host file and it worked as expected with private network IP settings.